# Print all categories in pyspark dataframe column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large dataframe where one column, called `location`, has just a small number of cities, for example: `["New York", "London", "Paris", "Berlin"...]`.

I want to print all distinct values on that column, such that I know if, for example, values for one city are missing. How can I do this, since the `.describe('location')` method is not helping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this you cant print the distinct values in the column `location`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.col('location')).distinct()
```

Comment: Sorry, by Distinct I meant just a list with all possible values, so not [London, Berlin, Berlin, Berlin, Paris] , but just [London, Berlin, Paris]. I think mine does the same.

Comment: Yours does also, but you are agregating data and performing an operation you didnt really need. With my code you get the result you want more efficiently :)

Comment: did it help ? @Qubix

Answer (score 2):

[describe](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe) method is for basic predefined statistics like count, mean, std, min, max etc. However, in order to find distinct values for any column you can use [distinct()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct) method.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Neeraj

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```
df.groupBy("location").count().show()
```